# Where clause for all rows matches between tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, rdbms

I have two tables like this:

```
table1                       table2

id  COL1    COL2        id  COL1    COL2
1   1   2               1   1         2
1   3   4               1   3         4
1                       1   5         6
1                       2   7         8
2   1   2               2   1         2
2   3   4               2   3         4
2   5   6               2   5         6
2   7   8               2   7         8
```

I want to find the id where it matches all rows for the id with second table

When I query in hana I am getting two id's

As only one id i.e 2 matches all rows with second table i am expecting id 2.

I tried all joins. Please help me.

Comment: Please try to help us on the formatting of your sample data and the desired output. I think you may be missing a column value in the list of values

Comment: Google and learn about the NOT EXISTS() function in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using string aggregation group by id.

After that I compared columns using Id condition

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `join` to get the matching rows between the two tables.  Then aggregate by the id and verify that the counts match:

```
select t1.id
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.col1 = t2.col1 and t1.col2 = t2.col2
group by t1.id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from table1 tt1 where tt1.id = t1.id) and
       count(*) = (select count(*) from table2 tt2 where tt2.id = t1.id);
```

An alternative way uses `union all` and aggregation:

```
select id
from (select id, col1, col2, 1 as from1, NULL as from2 from table1 union all
      select id, col1, col2, NULL, 1 table2
     ) t
group by id
having count(*) = sum(from1) and
       count(*) = sum(from2);
```

Comment: I think you may be only checking the id column. I think OP is implying from the sample data that all fields must match.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for ids that have records missing in table2, then return a list of ids that are NOT IN that list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT table1.id
FROM table1 table1
WHERE table1.id NOT IN (
        SELECT t1.id
        FROM table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
            AND t1.col1 = t2.col1
            AND t1.col2 = t2.col2
        WHERE t2.id IS NULL
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM Table1 t11
                  WHERE t1.id = t11.id 
                  EXCEPT 
                  SELECT *
                  FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.COL1=t1.COL1 AND t2.COL2=t1.COL2)
```

The trick here is that you find all records in `table1` and subtract (using `EXCEPT`) them from `table2`. Now the `id` that has all fields match with `table2` will return a `NULL` and therefore the `NOT EXISTS` will return this record for you.